# Countable basis of function spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the space of functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ does not have a countable basis.

I really don't know where to start with this one! Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  Since $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ have the same cardinal, it is the same question to ask whether the set of functions $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ has a countable basis.  For $x \in \mathbb R$, define $g_x : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$,  by
$$
g_x(s)=1\quad\text{if }s<x,\qquad g_x(s)=0\quad\text{if }s\ge x
$$
for all $s \in \mathbb Q$.  Then the set $\{g_x : x \in \mathbb R\}$ is linearly independent and uncountable.

Comment: Thanks, but how does the function g relate to a basis for the space of functions f?

Comment: It is possible to construct a basis for the space of functions containing the set $\{g_x:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: From the Axiom of Choice we get: (1) any linearly independent set may be extended to a (Hamel) basis; (2) any two bases have the same cardinal.